# Binomial distribution for two independence variables[linear combination of the two variables.]

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

My book introduced the below theorem.

Say $X$ and $Y$ are two independence variables $s.t.$  $X$~$B(n,p)$ and $Y$~$B(m,p)$

Then $X+Y$~$B(n+m,p)$

So, Let's generalize this idea by the variable, $Z = aX+bY$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then Is the $Z$ binomial distribution which is $Z$~$B(an+bm,p)$ ? (Here $an+bm \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \cup \{0\}$  )

(the notation $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ means set of the positive integers)

In my guess, the case of the $Z$ is a true statement when we considering the proof like the $X+Y $. But I don't have a confidence  my guess is right or not. What do you think about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X \sim Bin(n, p)$ then $\alpha X$ is given by

$$P(x, n, p, \alpha) = \binom{n}{\frac{x}{\alpha}}p^{\frac{x}{\alpha}}(1 - p)^{n - \frac{x}{\alpha}}$$